# API to fetch twiiter feeds via cron

Tags: php, api, twitter, cron

We have developed a product that is used for employee engagement. It provides a feature that shows tweets posted by members of your office if they have authorised the site.
The fetching of tweets is done by a periodic cron that is run at a regular interval at about 15 minutes. This cron searches for all the users who have authorised the site's app
and makes requests twitter for their tweets. For every user one request is send to twitter

Currently the system is using REST API (http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?user_id='xxxxxx') that is limiting number of request to 150 per hour. 
We cannot make authenticated requests as it requires the user to authorise the call every time, which is not possible while making the requests by cron. So, with just 150 requests 
and cron running four times an hour it is possible to fetch only 35-40 users data which cannot meet our requirements.

Also we have explored the option of Site Streaming API. But it requires a persistent connection to be established with twitter which would be difficult while using the cron. Another concerns with Site Streaming API is that it is in beta version and the website should be whitelisted.

Kindly assist us in selecting the best possible alternative that would help us meet the above mentioned objective

Comment: When you say "it requires the user to authorise the call every time", I don't understand. You should be able to authorize a user once, and then store their Oauth token and token secret on your database, so that you can use it for future requests without them having to re-authorize.

Comment: The streaming API doesn't require a whitelist. So better yet, look into the [140 dev](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-database-server/install/) server.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions.

- Create an account to follow the users who have authorised your app. Then, simply retrieve that timeline.

or

- Place the users in a "[List](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists)". Then make a call to [lists/statuses](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/lists/statuses)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain why you cannot stay logged in via Cron hwoever, as you are using PHP, can I suggest that you look at https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async/blob/master/EpiTwitter.php which authenticates your oAuth and then does what you want and closes the request.

If you cant do this with Cron, use serviceUptime.com to call a php script although the max time the script can run is 35seconds so don't try and pull all the lance Armstrong tweets back all at once. HTH.